# Get data from SQL Server without forwarding the port

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, mobile-website

I need to provide access via mobile web (asp.net) to small pieces of data (Just total's of the day etc.) that resides at our customers SQL Server, it would be to much of work for me to set up port forwarding and configure all ip's for each and every customer.

So I'm thinking of an alternate way to achieve that, I think maybe to make a small program running on the customers server that would push updates to our db, they may be an option. but I hope there's an easier way of doing that.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will [http endpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345123%28v=sql.90%29.aspx#sql2005websvc_topic3) work for you?

Comment: I see that with ALL solutions I'll have to forward a port on the customers server. right?

Comment: So the only way to avoid this would be to make a program that would constantly upload the data to a web server?

Comment: From what I understand you can create an http endpoint on server and expose services that clients can use.

Comment: but how will that info get to the www?

Comment: When you create an endpoint, you specify `PATH`, so wsdl will be located at `http://localhost/PATH`. I think the next step is setting up webserver to access it from the outside. Take a look http://codebetter.com/davidhayden/2006/04/21/sql-server-2005-example-http-endpoints-xml-data-type-xquery-xml-schema-collection-xml-indexes/